# What is the MySQL query equivalent of PHP strip_tags?

Tags: mysql, strip-tags

I have a large database which contains records that have `<a>` tags in them and I would like to remove them. Of course there is the method where I create a PHP script that selects all, uses `strip_tags` and updates the database, but this takes a long time. So how can I do this with a simple (or complicated) MySQL query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe there's any efficient way to do this in MySQL alone.

MySQL does have a `REPLACE()` function, but it can only replace constant strings, not patterns. You could possibly write a MySQL stored function to search for and replace tags, but at that point you're probably better off writing a PHP script to do the job. It might not be *quite* as fast, but it will probably be faster to write.

Comment: Now there is.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 42):

MySQL >= 5.5 provides XML functions to solve your issue:

```
SELECT ExtractValue(field, '//text()') FROM table;
```

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/xml-functions.html

Comment: This is the best answer for less antiquated MySQL/MariaDB versions. I would like to note that mariadb supports this as well. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/extractvalue/

Comment: Will not work on non-html text, unlike PHP's strip_tags. Also gives warnings for badly formated html.

Comment: perfect solution

Comment: this also don't convert HTML entities (like `&eacute;`)

Comment: it doesn't work when there's a <br> inside

Comment: I'd love to use this, but it doesn't work for any text that contains HTML tags that don't terminate, like `<br>` or `<img src="" alt="">`.

Answer (score 27):

Here you go:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `strip_tags`($str text) RETURNS text
BEGIN
    DECLARE $start, $end INT DEFAULT 1;
    LOOP
        SET $start = LOCATE("<", $str, $start);
        IF (!$start) THEN RETURN $str; END IF;
        SET $end = LOCATE(">", $str, $start);
        IF (!$end) THEN SET $end = $start; END IF;
        SET $str = INSERT($str, $start, $end - $start + 1, "");
    END LOOP;
END;
```

I made sure it removes mismatched opening brackets because they're dangerous, though it ignores any unpaired closing brackets because they're harmless.

```
mysql> select strip_tags('<span>hel<b>lo <a href="world">wo<>rld</a> <<x>again<.');
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| strip_tags('<span>hel<b>lo <a href="world">wo<>rld</a> <<x>again<.') |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| hello world again.                                                   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set
```

Comment: didnt work for me;  MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: `delimiter //  

CREATE FUNCTION strip_tags($str text) RETURNS text  

BEGIN  

    DECLARE $start, $end INT DEFAULT 1;  

    LOOP  

        SET $start = LOCATE("<", $str, $start);  

        IF (!$start) THEN RETURN $str; END IF;  

        SET $end = LOCATE(">", $str, $start);  

        IF (!$end) THEN SET $end = $start; END IF;  

        SET $str = INSERT($str, $start, $end - $start + 1, "");  

    END LOOP;  

END//  

delimiter ;`

Comment: DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS strip_tags;
    DELIMITER |
    CREATE FUNCTION strip_tags($str text) RETURNS text
    BEGIN
        DECLARE $start, $end INT DEFAULT 1;
        LOOP
            SET $start = LOCATE("<", $str, $start);
            IF (!$start) THEN RETURN $str; END IF;
            SET $end = LOCATE(">", $str, $start);
            IF (!$end) THEN SET $end = $start; END IF;
            SET $str = INSERT($str, $start, $end - $start + 1, "");
        END LOOP;
    END;
    |
    DELIMITER ;

Comment: even if I declare RETURNS text CHARSET utf8 the function returns question marks instead of accented characters, any clues please?

Answer (score 6):

I am passing this code on, seems very similar to the above. Worked for me, hope it helps.

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE iStart, iEnd, iLength   INT;

  WHILE locate('<', Dirty) > 0 AND locate('>', Dirty, locate('<', Dirty)) > 0
  DO
    BEGIN
      SET iStart = locate('<', Dirty), iEnd = locate('>', Dirty, locate('<', Dirty));
      SET iLength = (iEnd - iStart) + 1;
      IF iLength > 0 THEN
        BEGIN
          SET Dirty = insert(Dirty, iStart, iLength, '');
        END;
      END IF;
    END;
  END WHILE;
  RETURN Dirty;
END
```

Comment: I did a small rough benchmark on 5000 (~20mb) various plain text / html samples (scraped job descriptions). Output of your example is exactly the same as of Boann's, however your code took ~32s to process and Boann's just 7s making **Boann's solution 4.5x faster**. I'm just putting this here for future reference if someone will face the same dilemma as I did. Thanks to both of you guys.

Answer (score 3):

Compatible with MySQL 8+ and MariaDB 10.0.5+

SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(body, '<[^>]*>+', '') FROM app_cms_sections

Answer (score 2):

I just extended the answer @boann to allow targetting of any specific tag so that we can replace out the tags one by one with each function call. You just need pass the tag parameter, e.g. `'a'` to replace out all opening/closing anchor tags. This answers the question asked by OP, unlike the accepted answer, which strips out ALL tags.

```
# MySQL function to programmatically replace out specified html tags from text/html fields

# run this to drop/update the stored function
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `strip_tags`;

DELIMITER |

# function to nuke all opening and closing tags of type specified in argument 2
CREATE FUNCTION `strip_tags`($str text, $tag text) RETURNS text
BEGIN
    DECLARE $start, $end INT DEFAULT 1;
    SET $str = COALESCE($str, '');
    LOOP
        SET $start = LOCATE(CONCAT('<', $tag), $str, $start);
        IF (!$start) THEN RETURN $str; END IF;
        SET $end = LOCATE('>', $str, $start);
        IF (!$end) THEN SET $end = $start; END IF;
        SET $str = INSERT($str, $start, $end - $start + 1, '');
        SET $str = REPLACE($str, CONCAT('</', $tag, '>'), '');
    END LOOP;
END;

| DELIMITER ;

# test select to nuke all opening <a> tags
SELECT 
    STRIP_TAGS(description, 'a') AS stripped
FROM
    tmpcat;

# run update query to replace out all <a> tags
UPDATE tmpcat
SET 
    description = STRIP_TAGS(description, 'a');
```

Comment: Error in query (1418): This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

Comment: Sorry, my client had not enough privileges. Also see https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/phps-strip-tags-equivalent-mysql-function/5817/2

Answer (score 1):

Boann's works once I added `SET $str = COALESCE($str, '');`.

from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627940/remove-html-tags-from-record):

> Also to note, you may want to put a SET $str = COALESCE($str, '');
>   just before the loop otherwise null values may cause a crash/never
>   ending query. – Tom C Aug 17 at 9:51

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the [lib_mysqludf_preg](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg) library for this and a regex like this:

```
SELECT PREG_REPLACE('#<[^>]+>#',' ',cell) FROM table;
```

Also did it like this for rows which with encoded html entities:

```
SELECT PREG_REPLACE('#&lt;.+?&gt;#',' ',cell) FROM table;
```

There are probably cases where these might fail but I haven't encountered any and they're reasonably fast.

Answer (score -2):

`REPLACE()` works pretty well.

The subtle approach:

```
 REPLACE(REPLACE(node.body,'<p>',''),'</p>','') as `post_content`
```

...and the not so subtle: (Converting strings into slugs)

```
 LOWER(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(node.title), ':', ''), 'é', 'e'), ')', ''), '(', ''), ',', ''), '\\', ''), '\/', ''), '\"', ''), '?', ''), '\'', ''), '&', ''), '!', ''), '.', ''), '–', ''), ' ', '-'), '--', '-'), '--', '-'), '’', '')) as `post_name`
```