# Setting a column going though a function as a variable in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm working on making a query to search through a table in MySQL, and this is what I have so far:

```
SELECT strip_tags(html)
FROM threads
WHERE
    strip_tags(html) LIKE :searchQuery
ORDER BY
    id;
```

As you can see, that would require "html" to pass through strip_tags 2 times, and therefore would take longer time to execute the query. I plan on extending the query out more, so I could be using strip_tags even more.

Is there a way I can do this in another fashion?

Thanks.

Comment: do you have a function defined called `strip_tags`? there isn't one in mysql.

Comment: Yeah, I have a user-defined function. (taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654436/what-is-the-mysql-query-equivalent-of-php-strip-tags)

Comment: nice! Then maybe do a subquery so you only need to call strip_tags once like `SELECT tripped FROM (SELECT strip_tags(html) as stripped,id FROM threads)t WHERE stripped LIKE :searchQuery ORDER BY id;`

Comment: or you could using `HAVING` clause like `SELECT trip_tags(html) as stripped FROM threads HAVING stripped LIKE :searchQuery ORDER BY id;`

Comment: Thanks for answering, but sadly I'm still encountering the same error I had before, "Unknown column 'stripped' in 'where clause'". Did you verify the query worked beforehand? It could be my fault.

Comment: I mis-spelled it should be `stripped` and not `tripped`. but yeah i just ran it and it works [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5a87a/3/0)

Comment: Awesome, it worked. Lowered my execution time by a second (I extended the query as it was before) Thanks a lot. If you want, submit an answer so I can mark you as the answer.

Comment: there i answered posting both methods. you can test each one and see which one is better. and accept my answer :)

Comment: I think the `HAVING` might be faster since it's without a subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to use the function `strip_tags` once you can use subquery

```
SELECT stripped FROM (SELECT strip_tags(html) as stripped,id FROM threads)t WHERE stripped LIKE :searchQuery ORDER BY id;
```

or use `HAVING` like below

```
SELECT strip_tags(html) as stripped FROM threads HAVING stripped LIKE :searchQuery ORDER BY id;
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5a87a/5/1)