# Removing the HTML tags in the MYSQL table field

Tags: html, mysql

The below content is present in a description field in one MYSQL table. It contains HTML tags. Is there a way to remove those tags.

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small; line-height: normal;&quot;&gt;The Waste King Legend series 1 HP garbage disposer has a 2800 RPM motor, heavy cast stainless steel anti jam swivel impellers, and stainless steel grinding components. It is sound insulated, comes with an installed power cord, and has a front mount reset button and plumb EZ mounting system.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;

&lt;p&gt;- 6774B000DZGN7Q&lt;/p&gt;
```

Comment: once try with `strip_tags` if you are using PHP...

Comment: in mysql  is there a way

Comment: i don't know the answer for it in mysql.. But i think these links may help you, once give them a try...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654436/what-is-the-mysql-query-equivalent-of-php-strip-tags


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627940/remove-html-tags-from-record

Comment: As far as I know `strip_tags` only works with `<` and not with the encoded one: `&lt;`.