# how to use strip_tags in query for a field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written the below query in a function:

```
 $dsearch=mysql_real_escape_string($condition['title']);
 "select id, title , category, little, strip_tags('description') AS strip_desc,flag , 
       POSITION('$dsearch' IN title) AS pos_title,
       POSITION('$dsearch' IN strip_desc) AS pos_desc, 
    from    tbl_contents 
    where  title RLIKE  '[[:<:]]".$dsearch."[[:>:]]'
           or 
           description RLIKE  '[[:<:]]".$dsearch."[[:>:]]' 
    order by priority desc"
```

But the "strip_tags" does not work and I get errors. Is the method for this query wrong? 
thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What does - "strip_tags" does not work and I get errors_ mean? Which errors?

Comment: @il_raffa I get this error: FUNCTION   myDBname.strip_tags does not exist Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Comment: @F.Ahmadi Are you really trying to apply strip_tags on a _column_ in your table? And then second error `mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource` is the reason of your first failure (query failed).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not provide a function called `strip_tags`.
Assuming you use access your database using `PHP`, you can use the PHP function `strip_tags` on each row you fetched:

```
$strip_desc = strip_tags($row['description']);
```

See here:
[What is the MySQL query equivalent of PHP strip_tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654436/what-is-the-mysql-query-equivalent-of-php-strip-tags#7654551)