# Obtain record from MySQL strip tags then update

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a field (Description) in a MySQL database (poi). I wish to use php and the strip_tags to remove the HTML from all the records in the database. I then want to update the result to the same Description field in the database.

I have no problem with obtain the string and stripping the HTML, but I just can't seem to work out how to update the database with the result.

```
// check connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
  exit();
}
    $sql_article = "SELECT Description FROM poi";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql_article);

// Iterates through the MySQL results
while ($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
$Description_no_html = strip_tags($row['Description']);
printf("%s<br />\n", $Description_no_html);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally each row will have a unique id column that you can use to specify which row to update using a prepared statement:

```
$sql_article = "SELECT id, Description FROM poi";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql_article);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE poi SET Description = ? WHERE id = ?");
// Iterates through the MySQL results
while ($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
    $Description_no_html = strip_tags($row['Description']);
    printf("%s<br />\n", $Description_no_html);
    $stmt->bind_param("si",$Description_no_html,$row['id']);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

If you don't have a unique id column, then use the following statement instead

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE poi SET Description = ? WHERE Description = ?");
```

and

```
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$Description_no_html,$row['Description']);
```

**Alternative: stripping tags directly in mysql**

You can create a custom mysql function that strips tags (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13346684/3574819) and use the following query

```
 UPDATE poi SET Description = strip_tags(Description)
```

Disclaimer: I'm not sure how well the above referenced mysql `strip_tags` works, so your mileage may vary depending on your content.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt and useful answer, it worked!

I do have a unique id field, so I used that.