# mysql Sorting by Event Name

Tags: mysql, sorting

I'm going straight to the point here.

I'm doing a query where I sort the result by `event name`
however some of the event name has html tag on it.. how can I disregard the tag and go straight on sorting to it's actual name.

here's my query:

```
 SELECT * FROM 
 events 
 INNER JOIN venue
 ON venue.venue_id=events.venue_id
 INNER JOIN countries
 ON countries.country_id=events.country_id
 WHERE events.display = '1' 
 AND events.active = '1' 
 ORDER BY events.event_name_en ASC
```

but in my database there's a html tag.

the inter airport should not be there since it starts with letter `I`.
but my query returns that result since it targets the html tag.

my question is: how can I disregard the html tag and sort directly on the actual event name? thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654436/what-is-the-mysql-query-equivalent-of-php-strip-tags

Comment: sir @jakob, I have tried using replace.

ORDER BY REPLACE(events.event_name_en, '<i>', '').. but how can I replace multiple html tag? for example I also want to omit the `<u>` tag

Comment: for multiple tags you can nest `REPLACE`, check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
ORDER BY REPLACE(REPLACE(events.event_name_en,'<i>',''),'<u>','') ASC
```