# MYSQL how to search for specific words between tags

Tags: php, mysql

I need a list of glossary words/terms between tags in a document.

I could run a search for the total number of glossary terms in a document:

```
SELECT ROUND ((LENGTH(content) - LENGTH( REPLACE ( content, 
'class="glossary"', ""))) / LENGTH('class="glossary"')) AS count    
FROM article WHERE id = '1'
```

Output: 2

But cannot display the glossary terms only.

My document contains glossary terms in the following format:

```
<span class="glossary">Engine</span>
<span class="glossary">Gearbox</span
```

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Output should be:

Engine

Gearbox

Comment: I would just `SELECT content FROM glossary WHERE id = 1` and do the work in your php application

Comment: Hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654436/what-is-the-mysql-query-equivalent-of-php-strip-tags

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', '', $content)
```

I guess...