# mysql to extract the string from the column

Tags: mysql

i am using this function

```
CREATE FUNCTION `fnStripTags`( Dirty varchar(4000) ) RETURNS varchar(4000) CHARSET latin1
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE iStart, iEnd, iLength int;
    WHILE Locate( '<', Dirty ) > 0 And Locate( '>', Dirty, Locate( '<', Dirty )) > 0 DO
      BEGIN
        SET iStart = Locate( '<', Dirty ), iEnd = Locate( '>', Dirty, Locate('<', Dirty ));
        SET iLength = ( iEnd - iStart) + 1;
        IF iLength > 0 THEN
          BEGIN
            SET Dirty = Insert( Dirty, iStart, iLength, '');
          END;
        END IF;
      END;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN Dirty;
END
```

to return me the text within the column, but it is returning empty because it just displays nothing

here is what i have in my column, i want to extract the class

```
<i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the insert in SET Dirty = Insert( Dirty, iStart, iLength, '') - do you have a reference for it?

Comment: And what do you expect to be returned? What is input?

Comment: expected output to be this `fab fa-facebook-f`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have strips the tags, so your string `<i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>` without the tags is an empty string.

[What is the MySQL query equivalent of PHP strip_tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654436/what-is-the-mysql-query-equivalent-of-php-strip-tags)

If you only ever have one class in the string, check out the SUBSTRING and LOCATE functions in the MySQL documentation.