# Removing HTML tags while querying?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
Book::select('id', 'title', 'description')->where('status', 'published')->get();
```

It turns out that the 'description' column contains HTML tags.
Is it possible to get rid of these tags from the query (ie: without using a foreach loop)?

Comment: Your code don't create html tags. I think there is other reason to make it contains html tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55337029/7100313 and docs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue, you can try to do  something similar:

```
Book::select([
  'id', 
  'title',
  DB::raw("ExtractValue(description, '//text()') as description")
 ])
->where('status', 'published')
->get();
```

I haven't tested the solution, but it will most likely work.