# Remove everything after string

Tags: sql, replace

I have a table with a field that contains descriptions for items sold on my site.

In our infinite wisdom, when we first started the site, we pasted code for a Facebook Like button into the description, each just a little different, as it has product info in the link. We now have about 400 items with the code in it.

This is an example of what I'm dealing with:

> -Whipped Up, Fluffy Chocolate-On-Chocolate Taste; A Lighter Way To Enjoy Chocolate 
>   - 45% Less Fat 
>  
>  
>  < iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oursite.com%2Findex.php%3Fmain_page%3Dproduct_info%26cPath%3D33_36%26products_id%3D106&layout=standard&show_faces=true&width=450&action=like&colorscheme=light&height=80"
>   scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden;
>   width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true">< /iframe>

I want to remove the `<iframe` and everything past it. I have been looking around for examples using REPLACE and/or LEFT, but can't find what I need, as I am not very well versed in SQL language.

It will always be at the end of the products_description field, so I don't need to worry about saving anything past it, only before it.

The best I can come up with is

```
SELECT LEFT(REPLACE('<iframe%','<iframe%',' '),0)
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Thank you for any help you can offer on this, as it will take me much less time than editing each description.

UPDATE: Still haven't found an answer, after trying many variations of what has been suggested. It runs, but makes no edit to the column.

I also tried this, after finding it on another site. The same, but thought it might give someone an idea of how to proceed:

```
select left(`products_description`,instr('<iframe',`products_description`)-1) FROM products_description
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
trim( -- trim removes spaces before and after given string
    left(
        'some text < iframe', 
        locate('< iframe', 'some text < iframe') - 1
    )
);
```

For better understanding i did not removed space between `<` and `iframe`.

You may also take a look at this thread:

[Remove HTML tags from record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627940/remove-html-tags-from-record)

but this is discussion about removing tags only, and keeping `<tag>`text`</tag>` between tags. Anyway it will for for you, because you have nothing between `<iframe>` and `</iframe>`.

Comment: Thanks, had to put the space there or it wouldn't let me display the code.

AFA the 'some text', am I able to use a wildcard (%, right?) there? all the descriptions are different, so I can't specify what will be there. Or is the 'some text' part of the code?

Comment: This: 'some text < iframe' is input string. Replace it with your database field name in both places of my example code. And you cant use wildcards in LOCATE.

Comment: `SELECT 
trim( 
    left(
        'products_description', 
        locate('<iframe', 'products_description') - 1
    )
);`


This is what I tried, but don't get any results/changes.

Comment: 1. Have you added "FROM table" in your code? 2. Maybe put `< iframe` instead of `<iframe`

Comment: 1. I am in phpMyAdmin, and am navigating to the table in question, then running the code from there, is it still necessary?

Comment: 2. the actual string I am wanting to begin with, and remove everything after, is <iframe, no space.

Answer (score 1):

1. `REPLACE('<iframe%','<iframe%',' ')` will give you just ' ' - it searches first argument for second argument and replaces it with third.
2. `LEFT(somestring, 0)` will give you 0 characters string

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select substr(your_raw_string, 0, instr(your_raw_string, '<iframe') -1)
from your_table
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, and something similar to this I found on another site, posted in my edit above, using left. It runs fine, but shows no changes. I am not understanding what I am doing incorrect.

Comment: did you try substr()? This would only return the substring

Comment: Yeah, this is my code I used:

    select substr(`products_description`, 0, instr(`products_description`, '<iframe') -1)
from products_description

Comment: column and table names are both products_description. When I run it, I don't receive an error message, but no changes are made. Using phpMyAdmin

Comment: Try: `select substr(PD.products_description, 0, instr(PD.products_description, '<iframe') -1) from products_description PD`

Comment: Just tried that. I don't receive an error message, but performs the same way as your previous code. It gives me the results shown in the image below: [http://i.imgur.com/pfYjx.jpg]  Is it supposed to show the changed lines? No lines are being edited. Thanks

Comment: Try placing a space in between < and frame `select substr(PD.products_description, 0, instr(PD.products_description, '< iframe') -1) from products_description PD`

Comment: OK, tried that, didn't work. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/XRMDA.jpg) is something I noticed, when I clicked Inline Edit, it doesn't let me edit it. However, when I go to [Edit](http://i.imgur.com/EGvdj.png) it will allow me. Not sure why this is doing it, but thought it might shed some light on the trouble we are having.