# MySQL removing HTML hyperlinks while keeping name of link

Tags: html, mysql, sql, regex, database

So I'm trying to do the following:
A column in my table contains a bunch of text, amongst which is --

```
<a href="random.website.com>Text I want to keep</a>
```

which I want to change to:

```
Text I want to keep
```

Do also note that "random.website.com" is basically unique for each item, i.e.: it contains a different link for each item.

I am aware that there is a third party UDF called REGEXP_REPLACE but this is not available for me to use.

Is there any other to accomplish this? Appreciate any help of course.

Regards

Comment: You can write a script to change them. can you run php?

Comment: Perhaps you would find this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627940/remove-html-tags-from-record) to be useful.