# convert data with specialhtmlcharacters using sql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mySql dB with single quotes and other special html charaacters in my data set. 
How can i convert these char's into special characters like `&` (ampersand) becomes `&amp;`? 
PHP has `htmlspecialchars`, is there a SQL command that allows me to do this or would i have to create a new table using PHP?
This would be for a 1 time conversion, not on every look up.

Comment: Why do you want it in SQL, not PHP?

Comment: i have lots of rows and thought sql would be more direct

Comment: You will have to implement probably stored function for that purpose. Build-in, no there isn't, since SQL has nothing to do with HTML (nothing in common). And yes, not a good idea, will load DB with useless stuff to do.

Comment: Convert your text to HTML only when you put it in an HTML document. Don't store HTML in the database.

Comment: You are having an extremely bad idea. Do it in PHP, not SQL.

Comment: If you're piping the output through PHP anyway, it's better to put work on the PHP side than the database side. You could add another web server easily, but another database is _much_ harder. Also, PHP as you say has an existing, optimized function for it, MySQL does not.

Comment: if you do it in sql, it will put more load database - replacing all fetched characters with new character. I suggest you do it in php end.

Comment: Here is something you can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627940/remove-html-tags-from-record

Comment: so keep the single quotes in the table and when i output deal with it in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So keep the single quotes in the table and when output, deal with them in PHP, using [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)