# Need assistance removing tags from query

Tags: mysql

I have searched for an answer but I am very new at this. I have a query that prints out what is basically ticket status. The problem is, in the "Last Message" column, there are tags in there and I am not sure how to remove them since most of the answers I have found concern <> tags. Does anyone know how I can remove these tags and have the query print plain text? It is MySQL. This is an example of what one line prints: **`&lt;p&gt;I simply &quot;copied&quot; to a new file so I have no idea if there were macros in`** and I would like to have text like **`&quot;`** and **`&lt;p&gt;`** not show up on the results. This is displayed on a dashboard that the organization sees to view the status of various services. I don't want the data in the database changed, just what the output on the displayed query shows on the Dashboard. Please help if you can :)

```
    SELECT t.id as 'Ticket ID',rc.name as 'Reason Code', DATE_FORMAT(t.date_added,'%m-%d-%y %h:%i %p') as 'Date Opened' , DATE_FORMAT(t.last_modified,'%m-%d-%y %h:%i %p') AS 'Last Mod Date By IS', concat(users.fname, ' ', users.lname) AS 'IS Agent',         DATE_FORMAT(t.et_last_modified,'%m-%d-%y %h:%i %p') AS 'Last Mod Date by Client', concat(customers.fname, ' ', customers.lname) AS 'Client', max(messages.message) as 'Last Message'
    FROM `tickets` t
    JOIN ticket_reasoncodes tr ON tr.tickets_id = t.id
    JOIN users ON t.last_modified_by = users.id
    JOIN ticket_customers ON t.id = ticket_customers.tickets_id
    JOIN customers ON ticket_customers.customers_id = customers.id
    JOIN assignments a ON a.tickets_id = t.id
    JOIN messages ON messages.id = a.messages_id

    JOIN reasoncodes rc ON rc.id = tr.reasoncodes_id
    WHERE t.ticket_status_id =1
    AND (
    tr.reasoncodes_id =7
    OR tr.reasoncodes_id =23
    )
    GROUP BY t.date_added
    ORDER BY t.date_added DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

don't do this in mysql, do it in the layer of code after you get the result back - almost every web framework or lib has a 'sanitize' or other function to strip out tags.

Comment: We are basically using a website called Chartio to pull data and it displays it on a series of Dashboard pages. I don't think I see a 'sanitize' function.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Chartio doesn't have a nice sanitize function built in, but it is possible to write one in MySQL. Check out [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627940/remove-html-tags-from-record) for more.