# how can I remove html tags from the rows in mysql table?

Tags: mysql

I have imported data from old MySQL database, and inside there are many html tags.

So one of the cell in the row may look like this:

```
<h1>Hi</h1><p text align='center'>This is centered paragraph</p>
```

Is there any easy way of removing the html tags from the table? Something like search & replace with nothing or space those tags within the table?

There are some links inside which I would like to keep, but if that is too difficult, I would prefer to get rid of every html in the table.

Regards, John

Comment: Can you run the whole table through PHP?  If so, `$new = strip_tags($old)`

Comment: You can write a function in MySQL to remove HTML tags.
Refer- http://stackoverflow.com/a/13347316/3289313

Comment: Thanks Rishi. You can write this as an answer, and I will accept it because it solve my problem. I was searching for something like this about 2 hours, without any luck.