# Extract the URL from img src with a mysql query

Tags: mysql, function

Content of **test_instructions**:

```
<img src="http://www.test.com/quiz_images/poster_from_postermywall.jpg" alt="" align="" border="0px">
```

How can I extract the URL from the data of a mysql column?

I have used: [Boann strip_tags funtion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13347316/545138)

```
select strip_tags(test_instructions) from test_tb
```

It works for all other html tags but for img src it shows as null.
How is it possible fetch only the URL from img src?
If the column is null I get this error:

```
#2014 - command out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

Comment: The function you use removes every tag. That's why your result is empty, because the whole img tag is removed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example for you:

```
CREATE TABLE test 
(
  id int auto_increment primary key, 
  details varchar(250)
);

INSERT INTO test (details) VALUES ('<img src="http://www.test.com/quiz_images/poster_from_postermywall.jpg" alt="" align="" border="0px">');

select substr(
   substr(details, locate('src="', details) + 5), 
   1, 
   locate('"', substr(details, locate('src="', details) + 5)) - 1
) as 'src'
from test;
```

SQL Fiddle: [executeable demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d173/16/0)