# Extract multiple img src from long text in select mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a table named posts.

It contains id and post_content:

```
ID  post_title post_content
1   aaaa       <p>AAaa</p><img src="https://domain/uploads/aa.jpg"><p>Addd<img src="https://domain/uploads/assssa.jpg"></p>
2   bbb        <img src="https://domain/uploads/bbbb.jpg"><p>xxxxx<img src="https://domain/uploads/xxxxx.jpg"></p>
3   ccc        <p>aaaaa</p><img src="https://domain/uploads/aa.jpg">
```

I want to extract the image src from each post_content with specific domain. Each post_content has multiple images.

Like I only want to get images with url like this:

```
<img src="https://aaaaa.co.jp/uploads/">
```

Note: `<img src="">` can have width, height, class or id inside.

Like this:

`<img src="" class="" id="">`

OR

`<img width="" height="" src="" class="" id="">`.

I already tried this one from here:
[Extract the URL from img src with a mysql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28727238/extract-the-url-from-img-src-with-a-mysql-query)

Some of it returns the image url but some of it wont.

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT 
    post.ID,
    post.post_title,
    SUBSTR(SUBSTR(post.post_content,
            LOCATE('src="', post.post_content) + 5),
        1,
        LOCATE('"',
                SUBSTR(post.post_content,
                    LOCATE('src="', post.post_content) + 5)) - 1) AS 'src'
FROM
    tokyo_posts post;
```

So this is my desired output:

```
ID  post_title post_content
1   aaaa       https://domain/uploads/aa.jpg
1   aaaa       https://domain/uploads/assssa.jpg
2   bbb        https://domain/uploads/bbbb.jpg
2   bbb        https://domain/uploads/xxxxx.jpg
3   ccc        https://domain/uploads/aa.jpg
```

Note: I'm using a wordpress database. I'm gonna use this query for import image purposes.

Mysql version: 5.6.42

Comment: Doing this in PHP seems a better option to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't change the structure of your datas, this one is perfect for you.

```
SELECT post.ID,
post.post_title,
SUBSTRING(post_content, INSTR(post_content, 'src="') + 5
, INSTR(post_content, '">') - (INSTR(post_content, 'src="') + 5))
FROM
tokyo_posts post;
```

Comment: I haven't tested this but there maybe more attributes after `src` tag. So, calculating it this way assumes that `img` tag ends after `src` attribute since it looks for `">`. Also, as OP mentioned, the query needs to capture all image tags in the `post_content` and report it as a new row.