# How to remove html tags except <br> from mysql data?

Tags: php, html, mysql, tags

I have a field `Product_description` in mysql table, which has html tags. I want to update this field with removing html tags except `br`. I know I can do this with `strip_tag` but I don't understand how to accomplish this for the table data.

Comment: you can use php `strip_tags($text, '<br>')`

Comment: yeah but there are 15000 product description in table and i want to update also them then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To **remove all tags but** `<br>` from a text, you can indeed use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php):

```
$var = strip_tags($html, '<br>');
```

See an example [here](https://eval.in/614765).

From the **docs**:

> You can use the optional second parameter to specify tags which should not be stripped.

---

---

To **remove them from the persisted data** (not meant to run multiple times), you can create a heavy running script to be used once and update the values. Like this: *(You might want to use [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) too)*

```
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database_name');
$stmt = $con->query('SELECT * FROM table_name');
while($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){
    $stmt2 = $con->prepare('UPDATE table_name set Product_description = ? WHERE Product_id = ?');
    $tmp = strip_tags($row['Product_description'], '<br>');
    $stmt2->bind_param("si", $tmp, $row['Product_id']);
    $stmt2->execute();
}
```

That script would be for you to run it just once, so it's (arguably) ok if it's slow...

Comment: The OP stated: *I can do this with strip_tag but I don't understand how* ! I think he needs the full code !!

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH sorry, I don't get it. I showed how to do it, a working example and quoted the docs. With the given info, that's what there is...

Comment: yeah but there are 15000 product description in table and i want to update also them then?

Comment: for now i used to create a function in mysql but its removing all html tags in table.

Comment: I don't think the OP by *I don't understand how* meant the function parameters :D

Comment: @FirstOne its mysqli

Comment: @FirstOne good answer unfortunately I can't vote more than once :D

Answer (score 4):

Create function using below code :

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fnStripTags;
DELIMITER |
CREATE FUNCTION fnStripTags( Dirty varchar(4000) )
RETURNS varchar(4000)
DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN
  DECLARE iStart, iEnd, iLength int;
    WHILE Locate( '<', Dirty ) > 0 And Locate( '>', Dirty, Locate( '<', Dirty )) > 0 DO
      BEGIN
        SET iStart = Locate( '<', Dirty ), iEnd = Locate( '>', Dirty, Locate('<', Dirty ));
        SET iLength = ( iEnd - iStart) + 1;
        IF iLength > 0 THEN
          BEGIN
            SET Dirty = Insert( Dirty, iStart, iLength, '');
          END;
        END IF;
      END;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN Dirty;
END;
|
DELIMITER ;
```

And execute below query :

```
SELECT fnStripTags('this <html>is <b>a test</b>, nothing more</html>');
```

Comment: This doesn't address the user's issue of `br` tags

Answer (score 2):

for just one tag you can do this query

```
UPDATE `TABLE` SET column1 = REPLACE(column1, '<br>', '');
```

or make function for strip all html tags like this example

```
CREATE FUNCTION `strip_tags`($str text) RETURNS text
BEGIN
    DECLARE $start, $end INT DEFAULT 1;
    LOOP
        SET $start = LOCATE("<", $str, $start);
        IF (!$start) THEN RETURN $str; END IF;
        SET $end = LOCATE(">", $str, $start);
        IF (!$end) THEN SET $end = $start; END IF;
        SET $str = INSERT($str, $start, $end - $start + 1, "");
    END LOOP;
END;
```

this function found [from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13347316/6657160)