# Remove ahref tag from text mysql

Tags: mysql

i need to remove all links form column in a table. So for column entry like this:

```
 American drama film directed by <a href="http://www.google.com">Richard LaGravenese</a>
```

i need to remove the entire link, so it would end up like this:

```
American drama film directed by Richard LaGravenese
```

Is there a way to do this with a single UPDATE statement? (mysql)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it running a regular expression

try using [mysql-udf-regexp](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp)

take a look to this post, it can be useful

[How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You can create `strip_tags` function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `strip_tags`($str text) RETURNS text
BEGIN
    DECLARE $start, $end INT DEFAULT 1;
    LOOP
        SET $start = LOCATE("<", $str, $start);
        IF (!$start) THEN RETURN $str; END IF;
        SET $end = LOCATE(">", $str, $start);
        IF (!$end) THEN SET $end = $start; END IF;
        SET $str = INSERT($str, $start, $end - $start + 1, "");
    END LOOP;
END;
```

**Output**

```
mysql> select strip_tags('<span>hel<b>lo <a href="world">wo<>rld</a> <<x>again<.');
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| strip_tags('<span>hel<b>lo <a href="world">wo<>rld</a> <<x>again<.') |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| hello world again.                                                   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set
```

Thanks to the post https://stackoverflow.com/a/13347316/2689199