# How to remove html tags in search

Tags: php, mysql

I have inserted ckeditor data to MySql columns.

(there are three columns in my table) 
1[int]=id, 2[varchar]=page_name,  3[text] page_description

I am performing a search using `LIKE` on *name* and *description* columns with keyword *background*.

```
[page_description] column having this value <p style="background-color:#red"/>Hello how are you</p>""

$where = "B.page_author = C.user_id AND (B.page_name  LIKE '%".$search."%' OR B.page_description LIKE '%".$search."%') AND B.company_id = '$company_id' AND B.status = 'Active'";
```

[image: Sample of my mysql table given below]

My problem is that when I am searching its also picking up background saved in html tags and attribute , I just want to search on content only.

This page should not come in search as there no *background* keyword in _page_name_ or _page_description_ column, except in html tags

Hope its clear to you all, please let me know if anything is not yet clear.

Comment: where you have search and what result you expect?

Comment: I do not want this row should come in mysql result as there no "background" keyword is given in "page_name" or "page_description" column just in html tags , you can say , how to remove html tags and content in where clause when searching

Comment: see this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627940/remove-html-tags-from-record)

Comment: PHP has an handy function called [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php). Why not add an extra field in your database where you store a plain text copy of the ckeditor data made with this function? Yes, you use a bit more space in your database, but you don't need to maintain a rather complex, and perhaps slow, mysql function.