# Remove HTML tags from MySQL query using regexp filter

Tags: regex, doctrine

I'm trying to write a query in MySQL with a regexp to ignore HTML tags:

```
SELECT * FROM question WHERE question.enunciation REGEXP '[^<|</]center[^\>]' = true
```

I have the following records in DB:

```
ID  ENUNCIATION
1   <center>Random question</center>
2   center Text
3   Text center
```

I expected the following query result:

```
ID  ENUNCIATION
2   center Text
3   Text center
```

But the actual query result is:

```
ID  ENUNCIATION
3   Text center
```

Why does the query ignore the first occurrence of the term "center"?
Is my regexp incorrect? If so, can you suggest another solution?

I wish to resolve this problem without creating a function in MySQL.

Comment: Do you have only <center> as html tag?

Comment: You can find the answer here [Remove HTML tags from record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627940/remove-html-tags-from-record)

Comment: No, I have others html tags, it is an example, @RiggsFolly I wish resolve this problem without create a function in MySql