# Remove html from result of text sql select

Tags: mysql, sql

The Text column of my articles table contains html tags, the query returns a false result when I use a SELECT with LIKE:

Here is my request:

```
SELECT Text FROM articles Text LIKE '%aaa%'
```

I then try to remove the html tags before doing the LIKE of the SELECT. I tried using regexp_replace but it doesn't work

```
(SELECT regexp_replace(Text, '<[^>]*>|&nbsp;', '')
```

If you could help me. Thanks.

Comment: The only way to ***ensure*** you don't get false positives is to parse the html. Don't Do That In SQL. Read this question about extracting text from html in MySQL... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70973861/how-can-i-extract-text-from-html-in-a-mysql-column *(Instead, parse the html when the data is being ingested and store it in your DB in a more searchable structure.)*

Comment: Stripping HTML tags from text is a very complex parsing task requiring a full-featured and hopefully debugged HTML/XML parser. Most people don't attempt it with regular expressions. If you must do it with regular expressions, look for appropriate ones online, and tell your users to expect flaws.